# typescript multiple module project with es2022

Tags: reactjs, typescript, es2022

I have the following files
cli/src/index.ts

```
import print from 'core';
print();
```

cli/package.json

```
{
  "name": "cli",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "exports": {
    "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
    "default": "./dist/index.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/index.js"
  },
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "core": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

cli/tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../core"
    }
  ]
}
```

core/src/index.ts

```
export default function printHelloWorld() {
    console.log("Hello World");
}
```

core/package.json

```
{
  "name": "core",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "exports": {
    "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
    "default": "./dist/index.js"
  },
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

core/tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../core"
    }
  ]
}
```

and this file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2022",
    "lib": [
      "es2022"
    ],
    "module": "es2022",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "composite": true,
    "declaration": true
  }
}
```

But the following issue is raised "error TS2307: Cannot find module 'core' or its corresponding type declarations."
However the core/dist folder is generated without any issue